# Express sometimes picking wrong route

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am having a NodeJS based REST service exposed using Express (4.0.0) where I have two different routes like this:

```
router.get('/buckets/:bucketId/entities/bulk', getEntitiesInBulk);

router.get('/buckets/:bucketId/entities/:key', getEntityByKey);
```

When I send a request like this:

```
http://<server:port>/buckets/responses/entities/k3
```

The request is being handled by `getEntityByKey()` which I have defined there, but strangely when I bombard it with many requests it sometimes get handled by `getEntitiesInBulk()` and gets some error in response which is only thrown by `getEntitiesInBulk()`.

I am totally confused about how is this possible.

Comment: You have a conflicting design for your routes.  How does it know that `"bulk"` isn't a `:key`?  How should it know which route to pick?  You can remove the bulk route and in the first line of `getEntityByKey()`, check `if (key === "bulk"`).  If so, execute `getEntititesInBulk()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is confused because your routes are not unique. "bulk" will sometimes be used as a :key in the first route. Simply change the signature a bit, like

```
router.get('/buckets/:bucketId/entities/bulk', getEntitiesInBulk);
router.get('/buckets/:bucketId/entity/:key', getEntityByKey);
```

Comment: As you can see my request never had the word `bulk` in it so how come express got confused? Moreover express docs never said anything about this limitation, if you know any open issue please let me know.

Comment: Does the error go away if you change it like this? How are you calling the routes? Via the Browser?

Comment: @ThinkFloyd so what if you wanted to get an entity with the key "bulk"? Express doesn't know that's not a valid key (even a human can only presume), that's why it's confused.

Comment: @doldt you are right there. @Brasilikum I have tried to change it to `router.get('/buckets/:bucketId/entity/:key', getEntityByKey);` and looks like it is working now. To call routes I am creating the router like this: `var router = express.Router();` and then using it. To test I am sending requests using postman.